# NPM install error: fetch fail error

Tags: npm

I am trying to do an npm install having forked this code. I continue to get this error though

```
 fetch failed with status code 406
```

I have tried doing npm update followed by npm install but i still get the same error.

Comment: what is full command you issued ?  forked from what package ? on what OS

Comment: npm install was the full command, on Mavericks and forked from https://github.com/FreeCodeCamp/FreeCodeCamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by running the following command:

```
sudo npm update npm -g
```